# If $F$ is a field, what is $PGL_n(F)/PSL_n(F)$ isomorphic to?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $F$ is a field, what is $PGL_n(F)/PSL_n(F)$ isomorphic to?

$\textbf{My attempt:}$

Denote $G = GL_n(F),S=SL_n(F),H=Z(GL_n(F))$.

First I know that $PSL_n(F)=SL_n(F)/Z(SL_n(F)) = SL_n(F)/Z(GL_n(F))\cap SL_n = S/H\cap S$.
By Isomorphic Theorem, I know that $PSL_n(F) \cong SH/H$.

Therefore: $PGL_n(F)/PSL_n(F) = (G/H)/(SH/H) \cong G/SH$

And notice that elements in $SH$ has determinant like $\lambda^n$, so I think it contains all the matrices whose determinant has n-th root in field $F$, but I really don't know what $ G/SH$ should be like, killing all matrices whose determinant has n-th root in field $F$? Then what is it isomorphic to...?

By the way, I guess that the answer is $\mu_n=\{a\in F|a^n=1\}$...But I don't know how to get it.

Any help will be appreciated,thanks!

Comment: Look at $\rho : F^\times\to F^\times/F^{\times n}, \phi :GL(n)\to F^\times\to F^\times/F^{\times n},\phi =\rho \circ \det$, what is $\ker \phi$ ?

Comment: @reun I got it. I can use the isomorphism theorem one more time. But I'm wondering how do you think of this $\phi$ ? I think it's not that obvious unless we have a sense that the answer should be $F^\times/F^{\times n}$?